# How to programmatically change filenames

Tags: macos

Can anyone tell me how i could go about appending filenames in a specific folder with the string "@2x". I would prefer not to go to the trouble of renaming every single file by hand. Thanks.

Comment: Since MacOSX has a Posix interface, you probably could use a shell, or your C program, or some script language (Python, Ruby, Ocaml...)

Comment: I believe this belongs on superuser or apple.se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with **Automator** without any code.

Or, as you already know "**Xcode**" and **Objective-C**, here's an example that adds `@2X` before the name extension.

```
BOOL result;
NSString *fullPath, *filename, *newName;
NSString *dir = @"/Users/jack/Desktop/Untitled 1";
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [[fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dir error:nil] objectEnumerator];

while(filename=[enumerator nextObject]){
    if ([filename hasPrefix:@"."]) { continue;}//skip files that begin with a dot
    fullPath = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    if (!([fm fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&result]&&result)) { // skip directory
        if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:@""]) {
            newName = [fullPath stringByAppendingString:@"@2X"];// no extension
        } else {
            newName = [[fullPath stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingFormat:@"@2X.%@",[filename pathExtension]];
        }
        result = [fm moveItemAtPath:fullPath toPath:newName error:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Launch AppleScript Editor and paste the following script:

```
set appendable to "@2x"
set theFolder to choose folder
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to (files of entire contents of theFolder) as alias list
    repeat with theFile in theFiles
        set FileExtension to theFile's name extension as string
        set FileName to theFile's name as string
        set FileBaseName to text 1 thru ((offset of "." in FileName) - 1) of FileName
        set theFile's name to FileBaseName & appendable & "." & FileExtension
    end repeat
end tell
```

The script appends "@2x" to all files within the selected folder.
Simply hit the "Run" button and select any folder to execute the script.

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal you could run
`for f in *; do mv f 'f@2X'; done;`